# Ember bind controller property to query in another controller

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data

So I have a requirement that there should be a panel displaying a users unsubmitted widgets. Since it has to be in every view, I made into a component that accepts a binding to a count of unsubmitted widgets:

```
# components/unsubmitted-widgets.emblem
.well.text-center
    a href="#" My Widgets (#{unsubmittedWidgetsCount})
    button.small-button type="button" click="submitWidgets"
      strong Submit Widgets
```

I was thinking that the query for the widgets API would go into the application controller, which all other controllers can bind to

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend
  unsubmittedWidgets: (->
    @store.find('unsubmittedWidget', user: @get('currentUser'))
  ).property()

App.HomeController = Ember.Controller.extend
  needs: ["application"]
  unsubmittedWidgetCount: (->
    @get('controllers.application.unsubmittedWidgets').toArray().length
  ).property('controllers.application.unsubmittedWidgets')
```

So this fires off the request and I get a result. However the view doesn't get updated automatically. The view shows My Widgets() on whatever screen I'm on, and when I transition to another route where the view is present, I get the real value, but when I go back to the original page it's still not displaying everything.

How would I actually go about appropriately binding the value on the page to the length of the returned record set?

Comment: I think you should use [`@each`](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/) on your property.

Comment: That was it. Answerify it and I'll upvote and accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a property that has a collection as dependency, you must use [`@each`](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/), like so:

```
App.HeroesController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  identities: [
    Em.Object.create({ mask: 'Captain America', name: 'Steve Rogers', isAvenger: true }),
    Em.Object.create({ mask: 'Iron Man', name: 'Tony Stark', isAvenger: true }),
    Em.Object.create({ mask: 'Batman', name: 'Bruce Wayne', isAvenger: false }),
  ],
  justiceLeague: function() {
    var identities = this.get('identities');
    return identities.filterBy('isAvenger', false).get('length');
  }.property('identities.@each.isAvenger'),
  avengers: function() {
    var identities = this.get('identities');
    return identities.filterBy('isAvenger', true).get('length');
  }.property('identities.@each.isAvenger')
});
```

The `@each` will run your computed property code to get the count of items that match whenever one or more objects in the `identities` array gets the `isAvenger` property updated. For this example, it should show a count of two characters, considering one out of the 3 items has the filtered property set to false. The other list, watches the exact same path, but the "formula" is different, outputting the count of 1 character for the example above.